# Android WebView VERY SLOW

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-webview

I have an app and one of the tabs loads an external HTML page (contact form). Now the load time is tolarable, but once loaded the page is VERY slow when scrolling or endering input fields data.

I test this on LG G3 with Android 5.0.1 - it should be MUCH faster.

Please help.

Note - I read other posts on the topic, but I don't understand where to put possible solutions, and I tried a few things, but it is still very slow. I'm not a programmer, so please be gentle and add few details **for dummies**

I've tried adding these lines:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

But it did not help at all ... please tell me what to do.

Thank you very much!

here is my code:

```
package org.packagename.free;

import org.packagename.free.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Tab4 extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setContentView(R.layout.tab4);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            SharedPreferences data = MAINActivity.Preferences(this);
            int Free_Es = (int) data.getInt("freeEs", 0);
            Boolean mIsPremium = data.getBoolean("unlock", false);
            if (Free_Es == 1) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/contact.php?src=appprices");
            } else if (Free_Es == 2) { 
                //webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/m/contact.htm?src=tab");
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/m/leads.htm?src=prices");
            } else if (mIsPremium == false){
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/contact.php?src=appprices");
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/m/leads.htm?src=tab");
            }

            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);



            final Editor edit = MAINActivity.Preferences(this).edit();
            edit.putInt("freeEs", 0);
            edit.commit();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Tab4 obj = this;
            obj=null;
            System.gc();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I might have a similar issue. Occurs only on Lolipop. Will keep you posted if I come across something. Assuming you haven't been able to resolve this yet? Performance is good if I downgrade WebView on the device to the stock version